# Why does CTRL-SHIFT-F redraw several windows on my desktop in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, window, refresh, redraw

I have a 3 monitor setup and usually have Visual Studio 2008 open and the help on another screen and some other windows. When I press CTRL-SHIFT-F to open the Find and Replace Dialog, my desktop starts to redraw several windows on my desktop. That extremly slows down opening that dialog for me.

Btw. this also happens when I open that dialog by the pulldown menu. Interestingly, this does not happen for some other windows like the project properties in a C++ solutions. The other windows don't redraw.

I'm not sure if something goes wrong in VS or in all the other apps, but for example the msdn help browser redraws as well while the vista explorer does not - or I can't see it.

Is there a work around for this? Depending on the amount of windows open opening this dialog sometimes takes 15s.

Best regards
   Marc

Answer (score 0):

It happens for me, too, in VS2008 and can be incredibly frustrating, but I am afraid your only option is to create an incident for it at Microsoft Connect.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/

Comment: Ok I just did that => https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=485313
Let's see what they've got. :)

Comment: Huh, I just rechecked the connect website and they say that they were able to reproduce it and the fix is to buy vs 2010 when it's out! Unbelievable.

Comment: I'm not too surprised. However, at least for two bugs I've submitted, I initially got that same response, but then they ended up producing hotfixes for me which then ended up in an official service pack. So we may luck out and get a fix for this issue eventually. Of course, holding your breath should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Ctrl+H for find and replace.

Comment: CTRL+H has the same redrawing effect for me :(